# Windows 7 not installing over preinstalled ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, formatting

I bought a laptop recently and had ubuntu 12.04 pre installed. I wanted to install windows 7 so I wrote gparted live cd and booted into it, and formatted all the 3-4 partitions containing ubuntu, making the hdd an unallocated space of 500 gb. Then I made it into 2 partitions and formatted them into NTFS. But I've tried installing windows 7 through both dvd and usb which has worked on other laptops previously. The USB is not even being detected during boot and the  DVD starts to install but on pressing install now it shows the following error:

"windows could not retrieve information about the disks on this computer"

I can see in gparted that both the partitions are showing unmounted, does that have something to do with it? PLease help, i'm at wits end!
THanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your partitions with gparted and boot the system with the Windows 7 bootable media to try again.

If the USB drive is not being found as a boot-up device, either the motherboard is too old to support it, your BIOS is configured to not boot in that order, USB is removed from the boot order, the USB boot media needs to be re-created (sometimes, on another USB drive), or your USB drive is NTFS and the system can only read FAT32 for boot-up media.

If your installer still doesn't see the hard disk after it loads the initial installation wizard, then you may want to swap out the drive.

Comment: Agreed, and if deleting the partitions doesn't work, try creating a partition using Gparted.  I think it has the ability to create an NTFS partition.  If that still doesn't work.  I would recommend a hard drive diagnostic to see if your physical hardware needs to be replaced.